# Correctly Powering Lilypad Arduino

Tags: power

I am trying to correctly power a Lilypad Arduino that is attached with an HC-05, Lilypad temp sensor, and Amped pulse sensor. So far I have found that powering by plugging the Lilypad into my laptop and using three coin cells in parallel will allow for the Pulse sensor and Temp sensor to function properly. When I attach the HC-05, the readings become extremely incorrect. To remedy this, I attached the HC-05 to a 9v battery.

As I'm sure you can tell, I am novice to say the least. How can I properly power these components without damaging them. Thank you.

Update : I failed to tweak the program to reflect voltage change when disconnected from laptop. Temperature data much better and BPM is correct. Only issue that remains is the question of how to safely power all components through Lilypad. Thanks again.

Comment: a standard 9V battery is one of the weakest batteries available ... it is 6 AAAA cells in series, which makes the available current is very low

Comment: Something tells me that a Lilypad isn't meant to have multiple sensors due to its size and its specifications. I've seen the Lilypad be utilized for appearal like a wrist watch or something.

Comment: @KingDuken You are correct, the Lilypad probably isn't designed for this but, in theory, I would expect the only limitation to be power supply.

Comment: @jsotola Would it be safe to assume that my issue has to do with current rather than voltage? If so, would you recommend more current into the Arduino or simply powering the components independently from the Arduino? I'm not certain of the limitations of the device.

Comment: I'm just not sure that this answer is especially helpful in regards to the question that was asked. Perhaps a more helpful answer might yield a better upvote count?

Comment: @simon-marcoux, hey max, this is portal about "how you better solder 2 resistors< 3, 5, 100".. there is another specialized portal about 2 arduinos on even how to connect them.. just take a look. Here an answer is not even right, nor even privillige! Its an opportunity which may be or may be not satisfied.. we are scientists and you could be too if you join so you must understand..

Comment: The onboard regulator of the lilpad arduino is able to provide roughly 500 mA of peak current. The temperature sensor and the BPM sensor shouldn't draw a lot of current and since they are Lilypad ready, they can be powered by routing the + and - to their respective pins. The real bummer that you have is probably the HC-05. Finding 5v to power it will be tough. 

To power your whole system, I would use a lipo and the lipo connector. However, you will have the 5v problem that I previously mentioned...You will probably need two power source unfortunately.

Comment: @SimonMarcoux That makes sense. I only run into issues when I want to use the HC-05 along with the sensors, when powering it separately, I have no issues. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @JHolland for that particular Arduino board (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12049), the regulator input voltage (MIC5219) can be up to 12 volts. Depending on your board, you might find one with a regulator high enough to split your voltage at the battery level before the regulation occurs. That way, you only need 1 5v ish battery and you would be good to go...or go for a higher voltage with a 5v regulator.